# Converting lat lon into co-ordinates (in ft of m)

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, coordinates, trajectory

I have a set of latitude and longitude of a series of points which specific the trajectory of a vehicle. 
If I consider the first point as the origin (0,0), is it possible to convert the trajectory into a set of points with co-ordinates as (X ft, Y ft)? If yes how?

I would prefer to have the mathematical formula if possible.

I also have a related question. Does the conversion depend on the map projection I am interested in? If yes, the projection I would be interested in is Mercator projection with datum of WGS84.

Comment: WGS84 is a datum.  If you need a projected set of X,Y coordinates, then you are going to need to specify which one you want the coordinates in and that you want it in a WGS84 datum (ie UTM projection with a WGS84 datum)

Comment: The answer to your first question is "yes, of course". The answer to the second question depends on where the points are, and the input format. Can you please specify the point format and approximate location? It also might be useful to know the approximate distance from first to last (so we can figure out what approximations might be appropriate).

Comment: @DanPatterson, I am talking about Mercator projection with WGS84 datum

Answer (score 1):

You don't have FME do you? The CommonLocalReprojector transformer would do what you want, albeit that 0,0 would be in the centre and the data would need offsetting.

From the help:

***CommonLocalReprojector:**
Reprojects a set of features to a local coordinate system with units of meters centered on the bounding box of the features.
This transformer is useful if you need a number of features reprojected into the same local coordinate system.*

Answer (score 0):

I got [this](http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/cgi-bin/NDSFutility.cgi?form=0&from=LatLon&to=XY) BUT only thing is that I do not know how to automate it. I used it manually and it worked just fine. I am putting it as answer for it may be useful to someone.

If someone can automate it, it would be great.

**EDIT**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters/11172685#11172685) answer

Comment: Which projection and datum does this tool give results in?

Comment: To be honest I do not know and in fact when I used the formula given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters/11172685#11172685 the results were different...Still researching